# R which census division a longitude, latitude pair falls into

Tags: shapefile, r

I have the dataframe below

```
> head(cities)
  location_id longitude latitude
2       1  -79.3942  43.6724
3       2 -123.1070  49.2540
4       3  -71.0589  42.3601
5       4  -84.3880  33.7490
6       5  -97.7431  30.2672
7       6  -76.6122  39.2904
```

I downloaded the census division boundary shapefile from statcan which I read using

```
shapefile <- readOGR(".", "gcd_000a11a_e")
```

http://www.statcan.gc.ca/access_acces/alternative_alternatif.action?l=eng&dispext=zip&teng=gcd_000a11a_e.zip&k=%20%20%20%2014372&loc=http://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2011/geo/bound-limit/files-fichiers/gcd_000a11a_e.zip

I'm trying to find the census division each pair of coordinates fall into.

```
> summary(shapefile)
Object of class SpatialPolygonsDataFrame
Coordinates:
         min       max
x -141.01807 -52.58230
y   41.67695  89.99943
Is projected: FALSE 
proj4string :
[+proj=longlat +datum=NAD83 +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0]
Data attributes:
    CDUID              CDNAME             CDTYPE             PRUID              PRNAME         
 Length:293         Length:293         Length:293         Length:293         Length:293        
 Class :character   Class :character   Class :character   Class :character   Class :character  
 Mode  :character   Mode  :character   Mode  :character   Mode  :character   Mode  :character  
>
```

Comment: intersect or Reduce in R https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695677/how-to-find-common-elements-from-multiple-vectors did do this in QGIS but you want a 'R' solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've managed to get it to work using

```
# -
coordinates(cities) <- ~longitude+latitude
proj4string(cities) <- proj4string(shapefile)


dataset <- over(cities, shapefile) %>%
  cbind(cities.original)
```